# Eclipse running old version of code during debug, debug does not match code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, rft

I'm having trouble debugging a script in Eclipse/IBM RFT. When I run the built-in debugger on the following code, Eclipse executes it properly, highlighting a valid line of code.

[image: Proper Debug Execution]

However, when I modify this code (commenting), save, recompile, and run the debugger again, Eclipse acts as if the change had never been compiled and continues to run the same lines of code as if they were still there.

[image: Improper Debug Execution]

I understand that Eclipse must be running an older .class that is compiled from this code. Because of this, I've already attempted this after cleaning the build, cleaning its dependent projects, etc. Is there any way for Eclipse to show me the location of the physical file it is executing during debug-time?

Comment: You should set "Project->Build Automatically" so that any saved changes will always cause an immediate rebuild

Comment: I've actually already done that, is there a way to view the actual executing file? I don't think I'm having much trouble compiling.

Comment: I suggest you clean the project of that java file. It could force Eclipse recompile the .class